# Python 2.7 Test if SMPT Mail was sent

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib

I'm trying to do an fully automated Raspberry Pi using the SMTP Library to send an E-Mail with an attachment to a specific Address. But I don't actually know how to test if the E-Mail was sent successfully. And if it could not be sent for some reason, like no Internet connection, it should try it again after a few minutes.

I use an Raspberry Model 3 with Raspian GNU/Linux 8

I found something says this will work:

```
[..]
try:
    smtpserver.sendmail(sender, [receiver], msg.as_string())
    smtpserver.quit()
except smtplib.SMTPConnectionError:
    print(_logger.exception('SMTP Connection failed to %s on %s' % (host, port)))
```

I knew that it would not work because it's just a print command but I tried it just to be safe.
I got this Error-Code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "**Path + Filename**", line 43, in <module>
    smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP('***', ***)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 256, in __init__
    (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 316, in connect
    self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 291, in _get_socket
    return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

How can I test if there is an established connection and the mail was sent?

ps: My english is not perfect but I hope it's understandable

Comment: A common solution to this is to offload queueing and retry logic to a real mail server, called a smarthost. Your code still needs to send to the smarthost reliably, without crashing etc. Install a real MTA like Postfix, perhaps on a cloud service. It knows how to manage a queue of unsent messages, how to manage and schedule retry attempts, when to give up and regard a destination as undeliverable, etc.

Comment: This doesn't help for your immediate problem, of course. If the network cable is unplugged, sending mail is going to fail one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

You only except the `smtplib.SMTPConnectionError`, your post traceback is other Exception(so your e-mail is not sent):

You can except all the other Exceptions, then debug there:

```
[..]
try:
    smtpserver.sendmail(sender, [receiver], msg.as_string())
    smtpserver.quit()
except smtplib.SMTPConnectionError:
    print(_logger.exception('SMTP Connection failed to %s on %s' % (host, port)))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: I don't know what to do tbh. I used the code you wrote but it gives back the same error than before.

Comment: Have you debug which line the program crash？ maybe its not there.

Comment: I had to set "try:" to the beginning of the code. Now it just says "[Errno -2] Name or service not known". But this does not help me. I have to say that I'm an advanced beginner.